# Objective-C: NSURLConnection POST

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, http-post

What's the best way to send a `POST` request with `NSURLConnection`.

I see how the facebook-ios-sdk does it:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequest.m#L298-304

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequest.m#L109-165

But, that seems like a lot of code. Is that how it's done? Or, is there a better way? I'd like to keep the support for posting binary data, like images & files.

Comment: Are you open to using a framework? If so, I'd suggest [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Comment: No, thank you, I know about ASIHTTPRequest, but I'd like to do this with `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: I second @Moshe. `ASIFormDataRequest` can do what you want very simply.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's code is as complicated as it is because they're sending the data with a `multipart/form-data` content type. You are free to use a simpler content type, like `application/octet-stream` for raw binary data.

Answer (score -1):

You can try http://getsharekit.com/. Using this you can share in many social networks. Also you can share in a specific network also. If you refer to the documents there you can see how to send the images from a URL.